# Insert data to Postgresql from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

I have a code as follows:

```
import pg
import MySQLdb
db_postgre = pg.connect(dbname=...,user=...,passwd=...,host=.., port=...)
db_mysql=MySQLdb.Connect(user=...,passwd=...,db=..., host=...)
cur = db_mysql.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute ("""SELECT X,Y,Z FROM tab_a""")
data = crs.fetchall ()
for row in data :
    #INSERT THE ROW (X,Y,Z) TO POSTGRESQL TABLE.
```

The table in PostgreSQL (`post_tab_a`) is identical to the one in MySQL .
meaning it also has `X,Y,Z`
all types are `TEXT`.

Is it possible to perform insert directly from `cur`?  What is the easiyest way to do this insert?

Comment: So do you read data from one source, enter loop and insert row-by-row to another db? It would have poor performance.

Comment: @lad2025 The loop isn't mandatory. I just want to read from one source and enter another. I need something to mimic this query `insert into post_tab_a (x,y,z) select x,y,z from tab_a`. The issue is that post_tab_a is in postgresql and tab_a is in MYSql

Comment: Check: [Is there a fast method for exporting a large table from mysql to postgresql?](http://serverfault.com/questions/253876/is-there-a-fast-method-for-exporting-a-large-table-from-mysql-to-postgresql)

Comment: @lad2025 it won't help in my case. I can't do it with files. My table isn't large and I need to import records from it 4-5 times a day. after I import them I delete them from MySQL. I doubt it will be more than 100 rows per day. Performace is important but I can ignore it for an eaier solution. I'm just looking for a way to write the query as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply open another cursor for Postgre for the iterative inserts. There wouldn't be any named confusion as tables correspond to their cursor/connection objects:

```
import pg
import MySQLdb

# DB CONNECTIONS
db_postgre = pg.connect(dbname=...,user=...,passwd=...,host=.., port=...)
db_mysql = MySQLdb.Connect(user=...,passwd=...,db=..., host=...)

# CURSORS
mycur = db_mysql.cursor()
postcur = db_postgre.cursor()

mycur.execute("SELECT X,Y,Z FROM tab_a")

for row in mycur.fetchall():
    postcur.execute("INSERT INTO tab_a (X,Y,Z) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", \
                     (row['X'], row['Y'], row['Z']))
    db_postgre.commit()

# CLOSE CURSORS
postcur.close()
mycur.close()

# CLOSE CONNECTIONS
db_postgre.close()
db_mysql.close()
```